# subtract 6 hours from the default getdate() azure sql

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Using Azure SQL I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[receive_scans] (
[Id]                   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[barcode]              VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[record_created]       DATETIME     DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
[cart_id]              VARCHAR (15) NULL,
```

I see lots of places where they talk about changing it in a query, but could not find something related to a timestamp like above.

Azure SQL is 6 hours ahead of us and it is causing all sorts of problems.

thank you,

Joe

Addendum: If I needed to change it in the query returning the value or the client or local code I would not have worded the question the way I did.  In this instance we need to actually change the timestamp itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but this should work:

```
[record_created]   DATETIME default (dateadd(hour,-6,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UTC date function `GETUTCDATE()` and then change the UTC date to local time in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can query like this:

```
  select * from [dbo].[receive_scans]
  where [record_created]  <   dateadd(hour,-6,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you, but not at all related to the question.